# Does the presenter having knowledge of the Activity / Context a bad idea in the MVP pattern?

Tags: android, mvp, android-sharedpreferences

I've been playing around with the MVP pattern for a few weeks now and I've come to the point where I need context to start a `service` and access `Shared Preferences`.

I've read that the purpose of MVP is to decouple the view from the logic and having `context` within a `Presenter` may defeat that purpose (correct me if I'm wrong on this).

Currently, I have a LoginActivity that looks something like this:

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements ILoginView {

    private final String LOG_TAG = "LOGIN_ACTIVITY";

    @Inject
    ILoginPresenter mPresenter;
    @Bind(R.id.edit_login_password)
    EditText editLoginPassword;
    @Bind(R.id.edit_login_username)
    EditText editLoginUsername;
    @Bind(R.id.progress)
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        MyApplication.getObjectGraphPresenters().inject(this);
        mPresenter.setLoginView(this, getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        mPresenter.onStart();
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mPresenter.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mPresenter.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        mPresenter.onStop();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        ButterKnife.unbind(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.button_login)
    public void onClickLogin(View view) {
        mPresenter.validateCredentials(editLoginUsername.getText().toString(),
                editLoginPassword.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override public void showProgress() { mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }

    @Override public void hideProgress() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override public void setUsernameError() { editLoginUsername.setError("Username Error"); }

    @Override public void setPasswordError() { editLoginPassword.setError("Password Error"); }

    @Override public void navigateToHome() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

**Presenter Interface   ILoginPresenter.java**

```
public interface ILoginPresenter {
    public void validateCredentials(String username, String password);


    public void onUsernameError();

    public void onPasswordError();

    public void onSuccess(LoginEvent event);

    public void setLoginView(ILoginView loginView, Context context);

    public void onResume();

    public void onPause();

    public void onStart();

    public void onStop();
}
```

Lastly, my Presenter:

**LoginPresenterImpl.java**

```
public class LoginPresenterImpl implements ILoginPresenter {

    @Inject
    Bus bus;

    private final String LOG_TAG = "LOGIN_PRESENTER";
    private ILoginView loginView;
    private Context context;
    private LoginInteractorImpl loginInteractor;

    public LoginPresenterImpl() {
        MyApplication.getObjectGraph().inject(this);
        this.loginInteractor = new LoginInteractorImpl();
    }

    /**
     * This method is set by the activity so that way we have context of the interface
     * for the activity while being able to inject this presenter into the activity.
     *
     * @param loginView
     */
    @Override
    public void setLoginView(ILoginView loginView, Context context) {
        this.loginView = loginView;
        this.context = context;

        if(SessionUtil.isLoggedIn(this.context)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "User logged in already");
            this.loginView.navigateToHome();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void validateCredentials(String username, String password) {
        loginView.showProgress();
        loginInteractor.login(username, password, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUsernameError() {
        loginView.setUsernameError();
        loginView.hideProgress();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPasswordError() {
        loginView.setPasswordError();
        loginView.hideProgress();
    }

    @Subscribe
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginEvent event) {
        if (event.getIsSuccess()) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor =
                    context.getSharedPreferences(SharedPrefs.LOGIN_PREFERENCES
                            .isLoggedIn, 0).edit();
            editor.putString("logged_in", "true");
            editor.commit();

            loginView.navigateToHome();
            loginView.hideProgress();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        bus.register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        bus.unregister(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    }
}
```

As you can see, I passed the context from the `Activity` into my `Presenter` just so I can access the `Shared Preferences`. I'm quite worried about passing the context into my presenter. Is this an okay thing to do? Or should I be doing it some other way?

**EDIT Implemented Jahnold's 3rd preference**

So let's ignore the interface and implementation because it's pretty much the entire thing. So now I'm `injecting` the interface for the Sharedpreference into my presenter. Here's my code for the `AppModule`

`AppModule.java`

```
@Module(library = true,
    injects = {
            LoginInteractorImpl.class,
            LoginPresenterImpl.class,
            HomeInteractorImpl.class,
            HomePresenterImpl.class,

    }
)
public class AppModule {

    private MyApplication application;

    public AppModule(MyApplication application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public RestClient getRestClient() {
        return new RestClient();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Bus getBus() {
        return new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public ISharedPreferencesRepository getSharedPreferenceRepository() { return new SharedPreferencesRepositoryImpl(application.getBaseContext()); }

    }
}
```

The way I get the context is from `MyApplication.java`

When the application begins, I make sure to create this Object graph with this line of code:

```
objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new AppModule(this));
```

Is this okay? I mean I now don't have to pass the context from the activity into my presenter, but I still have context of the application.

Comment: You might also want to check an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49936324/4514796

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It has been some time since you asked this question but I thought it would be useful to provide an answer anyway.  I would strongly suggest that the presenter should have no concept of the Android Context (or any other Android classes).  By completely separating your Presenter code from the Android system code you are able to test it on the JVM without the complication of mocking system components.

To achieve this I think you have three options.

**Access SharedPreferences from the View**

This is my least favourite of the three as accessing SharedPreferences is *not* a view action.  However it does keep the Android system code in the Activity away from the Presenter.  In your view interface have a method:

```
boolean isLoggedIn();
```

which can be called from the presenter.

**Inject SharedPreferences Using Dagger**

As you are already using Dagger to inject the event bus you could add SharedPreferences to your ObjectGraph and as such would get a SharedPreferences instance which has been constructed using the ApplicationContext.  This was you get the them without having to pass a Context into your presenter.

The downside of this approach is that you are still passing in an Android system class (SharedPreferences) and would have to mock it when you wanted to test the Presenter.

**Create a SharePreferencesRepository Interface**

This is my preferred method for accessing SharedPreferences data from within a Presenter.  Basically you treat SharedPreferences as a model and have a repository interface for it.

Your interface would be similar to:

```
public interface SharedPreferencesRepository {

    boolean isLoggedIn();
}
```

You can then have a concrete implementation of this:

```
public class SharedPreferencesRepositoryImpl implements SharedPreferencesRepository {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    public SharedPreferencesRepositoryImpl(Context context) {

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {

        return prefs.getBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN, false);
    }

}
```

It is the SharedPreferencesRepository interface that you then inject with Dagger into your Presenter.  This way a very simple mock can be provided at runtime during tests.  During normal operation the concrete implementation is provided.

Comment: I like the last one as well, but looking at the implementation, I'd still need context right? So Inside my DI module, I have to specify somewhere the context correct? I ask this because I'm  clueless on how to set this up up injection.

Also, can the same be done with services?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Working well but I'm not sure how this is working behind the scenes. I'll update my question to show you what I did to perform the injection and let me know if this is not optimal.

Comment: What you've done looks fine.  The Application Context is now hidden from the Presenter because it's encapsulated within the SharedPreferencesRepository.  All the Presenter knows about is the repository.

Comment: Why repository do things like that? It's collection and it must keep set of objects of the same type. Am I wrong?

Comment: In this case `repository` is just the name of the layer which sits between the data (shared prefs, database, http, etc) and the Presenter.  It's an abstraction to allow the Presenter to not care where the data is coming from.  It could equally be called `DataManager` or whatever your preference is.

Comment: great answer, the presenter should be entirely agnostic of Android, in that case you could use the presenter over other application using something like J2ObjC and have an iOS app using the same core.

Comment: I am not using dagger for dependency injection, so I used your third approach. I got it working and presenter is free of android code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it then ok for me to create such a Repositroy for strings I need in my presenter? For example I want to log mixpanel data in my presenter but I need my projectId from strings. Instead of asking the view for the projectId string...

Answer (score 5):

This question was answered some time ago, and, assuming that the definition of MVP is what OP used in his code, the answer by @Jahnold is really good.

However, it should be pointed out that MVP is a high level concept, and there can be many implementations following MVP principles - there is more than one way to skin the cat.

[There is another implementation of MVP](http://www.techyourchance.com/mvp-mvc-android-1/), which is based on the idea that [Activities in Android are not UI Elements](http://www.techyourchance.com/activities-android/), which designates `Activity` and `Fragment` as MVP presenters. In this configuration, MVP presenters have a direct access to `Context`.

By the way, even in the aforementioned implementation of MVP, I wouldn't use `Context` in order to get access to `SharedPreferences` in presenter - I would still define a wrapper class for `SharedPreferences` and inject it into presenter.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the domain elements, like DB or network, needs Context to be built. Thay cannot be created in View because View cannot have any knowledge about Model. They must be then created in Presenter. They can be injected by Dagger, but is it also using Context. So Context is used in Presenter xP

The hack is that if we want to avoid Context in Presenter then we can just make the constructor that is creating all these Model objects from Context and not saving it. But in my opinion, it is stupid. New JUnit in Android has access to Context.

Another hack is to make Context nullable, and in domain objects there should be mechanism to provide testing instance in case of null in context. I also don't like this hack.