# Android MVP: defining Presenter in Fragments

Tags: android, fragment, mvp, presenter

I have done lot of search on Google and also on Stackoverflow but still I'm confused, so asking a question here.

I have this small MVP design pattern -

**SigninView.java**

```
public interface SigninView{

    void onSuccess();
    void onError();
    void onComplete();
}
```

**SigninPresenter.java**

```
public interface SigninPresenter {

    void signIn(String emailID, String password);
}
```

**SigninModel.java**

```
public class SigninModel implements SigninPresenter {

    private SigninView mSigninView;

    public SigninModel(SigninView mSigninView) {
        this.mSigninView = mSigninView;
    }

    @Override
    public void signIn(String emailID, String password) {

        if(emailID.equals("abc@example.com") && password.equals("123")){
            mSigninView.onSuccess();
        }
        else{
            mSigninView.onError();
        }

        mSigninView.onComplete();

    }
}
```

I want to implement the **SigninView** on a ***Fragment*** and define the **SigninPresenter** there itself like this -

```
SigninPresenter mSigninPresenter = new SigninModel(view_of_mvp);
mSigninPresenter.signIn("adadada", "asads");
```

See one reference here. I want to implement a View and define a Presenter like this but on a Fragment - https://github.com/ashokslsk/Comprehensive-MVP/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ashokslsk/mvpexample/MainActivity.java

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to pass the context, but rather the implementation of your SigninView. So you need to make your fragment implement `SigninView`

```
MyFragment implements SigninView
```

and simply initialize the presenter with `this`, instead of context. In fact, you presenter shouldn't know much about the Android SDK, so it shouldn't deal with contexts. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303510/does-the-presenter-having-knowledge-of-the-activity-context-a-bad-idea-in-the).

```
SigninPresenter mSigninPresenter = new SigninModel(this);
```

**EDIT:**

You had the activity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SigninView
```

All you have to do is make your fragment implement SigninView:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements SigninView
```

And then, in onCreateView you can initialize the presenter like this:

```
signinPresenter = new SigninPresenterImpl(this);
```

Comment: Another thing. Do developers don't use Fragments in MVP generally like I'm doing ? I'm asking this question because I searched a lot but I didn't actually find something like this. I like to keep things simple.

Comment: We actually do, it really depends on your needs. The point is the View in MVP can be an Activity, a Fragment or even a View object. If you take a look an this code sample by Google https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/taskdetail/TaskDetailFragment.java they use the fragment as a View in MVP,

Comment: So it's pretty usual to have fragments as the V in MVP, in the end it depends on your needs.

Comment: In the answer above, how can we pass 'this' as context in a fragment ?

Comment: Fragments don't extend from Context (like activities and services) so you can't pass a fragment as a context. You can call this.getContext() to get the context from a fragment though

Comment: See I have updated my question. When defining a presenter in the Fragment, I need a pass a View of MVP to the Presenter constructor. Thats where I'm having problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168562/discussion-between-gissipi-453-and-levi-albuquerque).

Comment: thanks. Accepted as correct answer. That solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your View already implements `getContext()`. Just add it in your interface and call it in your `SigninModel` :

**SigninPresenter.java**

```
public interface SigninView {

    void onSuccess();
    void onError();
    void onComplete();

    Context getContext();
}
```

**SigninModel.java**

```
mSigninView.getContext();
```

Comment: Is this a hack or the standard way ? Not pointing you, I just want to know. As i told, I was getting confused in this thing.

Comment: This is not a hack, this is what Interface is made for.